# Como passar nomes de um arquivo para um DataGridView usando FolderBrowserDialog?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, arquivo, path

Como eu faço para passar o nome dos arquivos que foram achados dentro da pasta selecionada?

Até agora eu só consegui fazer para ele pegar o caminho do do arquivo e passar para o `DataGridView` e agora eu quero fazer para ele passar o nome também.

Aqui vai a parte do código para o `FolderBrowserDialog`.

```
private void btnDiretorio_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        this.grvShowFile.Rows.Clear();
        folderBrowserDialog.RootFolder = Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory;
        folderBrowserDialog.SelectedPath = openFileDialog.InitialDirectory;
        folderBrowserDialog.ShowNewFolderButton = true;
        openFileDialog.Filter = "Form (*.frm)|*.frm|" + "All files (*.*)|*.*";
        DialogResult result = folderBrowserDialog.ShowDialog();

        if (result == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            List<string> selectedPath = listaArquivos(folderBrowserDialog.SelectedPath);
            foreach (string s in selectedPath)
            {
                grvShowFile.Rows.Add(s);
            }
        }
    }

    public List<string> listaArquivos(string dir)
    {
        List<string> lstDirs = Directory.GetDirectories(dir).ToList();
        List<string> lstFiles = Directory.GetFiles(dir).ToList();
        List<string> lstFilesAux = new List<string>();

        foreach(string ldir in lstDirs)
            lstFilesAux = listaArquivos(ldir);

        lstFiles.AddRange(lstFilesAux);
        return lstFiles;
    }
```

E se puderem me falar também como eu faço para ele buscar apenas os arquivos que estão no filtro eu agradeceria.

Comment: Não entendi seu problema. O caminho inclui o nome do arquivo. Você quer pegar só o nome do arquivo que está dentro do caminho? Também não entendi o que está errado com a segunda parte da pergunta.

Comment: Sim, o que eu quero é pegar o nome do arquivo, por exemplo: Logs.txt

Nesse código o que ele está pegando é só o caminho por exemplo "C:\Logs.txt", entendeu? no meu DataGridView tem esses 2 campos um para o nome do arquivo e outro para o caminho do arquivo e no momento ele só está pegando o caminho do arquivo.

Comment: Tem alguma coisa que precisa melhorar nas respostas que você recebeu nas suas perguntas? Você não votou nelas e nem aceitou nenhuma. Veja [tour] Se acha que o objetivo principal desta pergunta foi alcançado você pode aceitar a resposta. Também poderá votar em tudo no site que achar útil, não só nas coisas ligadas aos seus posts.

Answer (score 1):

Para pegar só o nome do arquivo contido em um caminho é usado o método [`Path.GetFileName()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getfilename?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=netcore-3.1#System_IO_Path_GetFileName_System_String_).

Provavelmente fará algo assim:

```
List<string> selectedPath = listaArquivos(folderBrowserDialog.SelectedPath);
foreach (string s in selectedPath) {
    grvShowFile.Rows.Add(Path.GetFileName(s));
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/WinForms/FolderBrowserDialog.cs).

Comment: Obrigado eu agora ele está pegando ambos, o nome e o caminho :) e a parte da restrição de arquivos? Como eu posso fazer isso?

Comment: Eu não entendi o que você quer fazer com isto, me parece que já está fazendo mas você parece querer outra coisa. Tente explicar melhor o que está ocorrendo de errado e o que está faltando fazer.

Comment: No momento ele está pegando todos os arquivos dentro da pasta. A função só está acessando o diretório e os subdiretórios e pegando tudo que está ali dentro. O que eu quero da minha aplicação é: Pegar somente os arquivos ".fmr" de uma pasta, eu coloquei um openFileDialog.Filter porém não sei se é correto fazer isso.

Comment: Tira esta parte: `"All files (*.*)|*.*"`. Estava tentando entender esse método `listaArquivos` (talvez desse p/ eliminar os arquivos com extensões indesejadas para o código ficar mais robusto) e ele me parece bem confuso, não sei se está fazendo o que você realmente precisa. Mesmo que esteja, não é um código muito bonito. Mas aí já é outro problema. Talvez até fosse o caso de fazer uma pergunta nova com este problema, senão a pergunta fica muito ampla.

Comment: Eu tirei e modifiquei também para outro tipo de arquivo mas ele ainda está pegando tudo.

Comment: Eu vou pesquisar mais mas acho que você deve fazer outra pergunta sobre isto para ficar organizado. Detalhe bem esta parte para todo mundo entender. Coloque todas as partes relevantes. Por exemplo, você não colocou de onde vem a variável `openFileDialog`.

Comment: Tudo bem obrigado, eu vou fazer outra pergunta mais detalhada e também vou organizar o código, comentar mais ele e tal. Obrigado pela ajuda.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar a classe [`FileInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.io.fileinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) que fornece propriedades e métodos de instância para a criação, cópia, exclusão, deslocamento e abertura de arquivos.

```
List<string> selectedPath = listaArquivos(folderBrowserDialog.SelectedPath);
foreach (string s in selectedPath)
{
    FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(s);
    grvShowFile.Rows.Add(fileInfo.Name);
}
```