# Como usar Filter no FolderBrowserDialog

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, arquivo

Eu gostaria de saber como faço para colocar um filtro em determinado arquivos usando c#.

Bom é mais ou menos assim, eu estou fazendo uma aplicação em c# que deve abrir alguns tipos de arquivos ( no caso .frm ), na parte "manual" que seria quando o usuário seleciona 1 ou mais arquivos a serem carregados e passados no DataGridView ele está usando o filtro sem grandes problemas .

```
 openFileDialog.Filter = "Form (*.frm)|*.frm|" + "All files (*.*)|*.*"; //Filtro de arquivos a serem selecionados
```

*Nota: estou usando o openFileDialog para fazer a seleção manual dos arquivos.*

Já na segunda parte ( que é a seleção de uma pasta ou de uma subpasta ) é a que estou com problemas na hora de usar esse filtro. Eu já tinha feito uma outra pergunta aqui que era

["Como passar nomes de um arquivo para um DataGridView usando FolderBrowserDialog"](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/43996/como-passar-nomes-de-um-arquivo-para-um-datagridview-usando-folderbrowserdialog/43998?noredirect=1#comment87713_43998)

Agora minha outra dúvida é: Como eu faço para usar o filtro de seleção de arquivos no FolderBrowserDialog. Usando o OpenFileDialog ele já te dava essa opção de usar o filter - como é visto ali em cima no meu exemplo - mas já no FolderBrowserDialog ele não te da essa opção de colocar um filtro. Eu já havia tentado fazer o filtro da mesma forma do meu exemplo a cima porém não funcionou. Segue a parte do código em que estou usando o FolderBrowserDialog.

```
 private void btnDiretorio_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            this.grvShowFile.Rows.Clear();
            folderBrowserDialog.RootFolder = Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory;
            folderBrowserDialog.SelectedPath = openFileDialog.InitialDirectory;
            folderBrowserDialog.ShowNewFolderButton = true;
            openFileDialog.Filter = "Form (*.frm)|*.frm"; //Filtro de arquivos a serem selecionados
            DialogResult result = folderBrowserDialog.ShowDialog();

            if (result == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                List<string> selectedPath = listaArquivos(folderBrowserDialog.SelectedPath);
                foreach (string s in selectedPath)
                {
                    grvShowFile.Rows.Add(Path.GetFileName(s), s); //Adiciona o nome e o caminho dos arquivos nas respectivas ordens ( Bendito seja o Path.GetFileName() )
                }
            }
        }

        public List<string> listaArquivos(string dir)
        {
            List<string> lstDirs = Directory.GetDirectories(dir).ToList();
            List<string> lstFiles = Directory.GetFiles(dir).ToList();
            List<string> lstFilesAux = new List<string>();
            foreach(string ldir in lstDirs)
                lstFilesAux = listaArquivos(ldir);

            lstFiles.AddRange(lstFilesAux);
            return lstFiles;
        }
```

*Nota: Eu usei um `List<>` para fazer a verificação do diretório e a verificação dos subdiretórios caso tenha algum.*

Bom espero que tenha explicado bem a minha dúvida, toda explicação é super bem vinda aqui.

Comment: `List<string> lstDirs = Directory.GetDirectories(dir, "*.frm", SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToList();`, ve se isso te ajuda

Comment: Não amigo, ele ainda está pegando todos os arquivos de dentro do diretório.

Comment: Foi mal, errei o método que tinha que alterar tente o seguinte `public List<string> listaArquivos(string dir)
        {
            List<string> lstFiles = Directory.GetFiles(dir, "*.frm", SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToList();         
            return lstFiles;
        }`

Comment: Obrigado agora deu certo !!

Comment: @RodolfoOlivieri Dê uma olhada no [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 3):

Talvez seu problema não seja na seleção do diretório e sim dos arquivos. Eu já respondi algo assim em [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/30800/101). Você deve usar o [`Directory.GetFiles()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getfiles?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=netcore-3.1#System_IO_Directory_GetFiles_System_String_System_String_System_IO_SearchOption_) com opções de filtro:

```
public List<string> listaArquivos(string dir)
{
    List<string> lstDirs = Directory.GetDirectories(dir).ToList();
    List<string> lstFiles = Directory.GetFiles(dir, "*.frm", SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToList();
    List<string> lstFilesAux = new List<string>();
    foreach(string ldir in lstDirs)
        lstFilesAux = listaArquivos(ldir);

    lstFiles.AddRange(lstFilesAux);
    return lstFiles;
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/WinForms/ListFiles.cs).

Ainda tenho dúvidas se o resto do código está fazendo o que você deseja. Mas sem maiores informações posso estar errado. Talvez o que você queira fazer é algo mais simples:

```
private void btnDiretorio_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    this.grvShowFile.Rows.Clear();
    folderBrowserDialog.RootFolder = Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory;
    folderBrowserDialog.SelectedPath = openFileDialog.InitialDirectory;
    openFileDialog.Filter = "Form (*.frm)|*.frm"; //Filtro de arquivos a serem selecionados
    DialogResult result = folderBrowserDialog.ShowDialog();
    if (result == DialogResult.OK) {
        List<string> selectedPath = Directory.GetFiles(folderBrowserDialog.SelectedPath,
                                         "*.frm", SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToList();
        foreach (string s in selectedPath) grvShowFile.Rows.Add(Path.GetFileName(s), s); //Adiciona o nome e o caminho dos arquivos nas respectivas ordens ( Bendito seja o Path.GetFileName() )
    }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/WinForms/ListFiles2.cs).

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda amigo, eu testei aqui e funcionou o seu e o do do Pablo ali em cima !!

Comment: pra que a recursividade? o GetFiles não vai procurar nos subdiretórios?

Comment: E o que eu venho perguntando pra ele desde a pergunta anterior dele.

Comment: A primeiro momento tinham pedido para mim testar com recursividade e eu não alterei ainda. Estou apenas fazendo testes.

Comment: O método que usa recursividade é melhor. Se houverem diretórios com permissões negadas ao usuário corrente, a função `Directory.GetFiles` vai lançar uma exceção. A única forma de tratar pontualmente essas exceções, é navegando para cada diretório manualmente, e tratando as exceções relacionadas a permissão de acesso. Se for usada a opção que já retorna tudo, se houver um único diretório com permissão negada na árvore de diretórios, a exceção será lançada, e nada será retornado.

Comment: Para verificar o que eu disse anteriormente, basta um simples teste: `Directory.GetFiles("C:\\", "*.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories);` cara, isso vai dar pau com certeza!!!

Comment: A exceção a ser tratada é a `System.UnauthorizedAccessException`, ao chamar `Directory.GetFiles`, permitindo assim se esquivar dos diretórios sem acesso permitido.

Comment: @MiguelAngelo Concordo. O difícil é as pessoas quererem fazer todo tratamento necessário já que quase sempre ela não terá esse problema. Eu faria algo mais robusto mas as pessoas querem apenas ver funcionando em condições ideais.

Answer (score 2):

Bom, já que me exemplo também funcionou, acredito que ele seja um pouco melhor do que usar recursividade.

```
public List<string> listaArquivos(string dir)
    {
        List<string> lstFiles = Directory.GetFiles(dir, "*.frm", SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToList();         
        return lstFiles;
    }
```